# javascript Remover function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm writing a kinda expenses management app. I'm stuck with writing a function which can remove the parentNode and the respective children wherever it's called.

I have a remove button next to all of my Items in my expenses list. BTW I've already tried using the this keyword to get the parent node but it returns undefined. My code:

```
function remover(){
  var x = this.parentNode.parentNode;
}
```

Comment: Can you share all related code, please ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. When you post a question about some code you have written not working, you need to provide three things. 1. The behaviour you are seeing and why you think it's wrong, 2. The minimum code and/or steps necessary to demonstrate the behaviour you are seeing, and 3. The behaviour you would like to see. Unless you provide these things it's very difficult to help you

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. How can i share all my project here (including CSS and HTML file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in that target element as an argument to the function, then use `.parentElement` to access the parent element and simply apply `.remove()` to remove the parent element from DOM.

```js
function remove(that) {

  that.parentElement.remove();

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child" onclick="remove(this)">Click me to remove my parent!</div>
</div>
```